# Use the moment generating function to show that the sample mean $\bar{X}$ also has a Gamma distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n$ be iid sample from $X\sim Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$. Use the moment generating function to show that the sample mean $\bar{X}$ also has a Gamma distribution.

---

Is my proof correct as follows?

Note the MGF of Gamma distribution is given by
$$
M_{X}(t)=(1-\beta t)^{-\alpha}, 
$$
for $\alpha, \beta>0$ and $t<1/\beta$.

The MGF of $\bar{X}$ is
$$
M_{\bar{X}}(t)=E[\exp(t\bar{X})]=(E[e^{tX_1/n}])^n=(1-\beta t/n)^{-\alpha n}
$$

Take $\beta'=\beta/n$ and $\alpha'=\alpha n$. It has the forms of the MGF of Gamma, so we prove it.

Comment: Yes:  intuitively $\sum X_i \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha n, \beta)$ so $\bar X \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha n, \beta /n)$ if $\alpha$ is the shape parameter and $\beta$ the scale parameter, or $\bar X \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha n, \beta n)$ if $\alpha$ is the shape parameter and $\beta$ the rate parameter.  Your use of the MGF provides a proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the answer is correct (do note that there are two parametrizations of the Gamma distribution so it may be good the denote which one is used).

The one thing I would add would be the following: For two r.v. $X_1$ and $X_2$ with mgfs $M_{X_1}(s)$ and $M_{X_2}(s)$ and cdfs $F_{X_1}(x)$ and $F_{X_2}(x)$, it holds that if
\begin{equation} 
 M_{X_1}(s) = M_{X_2}(s) \Rightarrow F_{X_1}(x) = F_{X_2}(x) 
\end{equation}

which I know you are going for but it's nice to see it stated explicitly.